# How return only document created after perform save() with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When I use `return await Model.save()` they return a lot of data. There is a way to return the document only?

Code:

```js
async (data) =>{
    const charData = new MyModel({
        steamId: data.steam,
        phone: data.phone,
        registration: data.registration,
    })
    return await MyModel.save()
}
```

I've searched in many websites but I didnt find any example using async functions.

There is a example that `MyModel.save()` are returning:
[image: MyModel.save() returns]

So, I want get only _doc object instead it all when `return await MyModel.save()`

Comment: assuming this "document" you want is a property of whatever `.save` returns, `const x = await MyModel.save(); return x.something` - where `something` is the "docoument" - otherwise, what is this "document" you seek?

Comment: @JaromandaX As doc says (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) They return fulfill promisse.

I'm looking for the same result of .lean() when I perform a query/find
(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

Comment: as it says `If save is successful, the returned promise will fulfill with the document saved.` - so, you are returning the saved document - you're probably using whatever calls `async (data) =>{` incorrectly ... you realise your function returns a Promise, because `async` functions return a Promise

Comment: as an aside ... you never need to `return await somePromise` - you can just `return somePromise` - and, in fact, in your case, the function doesn't even need to be `async` since you never actually need to `await` - so remove `async` and remove `await` and make sure whatever calls your function does so with the expected result being a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX I've edited the question and provided the result that I'm getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Document.prototype.toObject()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toObject) converts a mongoose document into the plain javascript object representation.

```
async (data) =>{
    const charData = new MyModel({
        steamId: data.steam,
        phone: data.phone,
        registration: data.registration,
    })
    await charData.save()
    return charData.toObject({ getters: true })
}
```

Note the options which affect how the document is represented:

> - `getters` apply all getters (path and virtual getters), defaults to false
> - `aliases` apply all aliases if `virtuals=true`, defaults to true
> - `virtuals` apply virtual getters (can override getters option), defaults to false
> - `minimize` remove empty objects, defaults to true
> - `transform` a transform function to apply to the resulting document before returning
> - `depopulate` depopulate any populated paths, replacing them with their original refs, defaults to false
> - `versionKey` whether to include the version key, defaults to true
> - `flattenMaps` convert Maps to POJOs. Useful if you want to JSON.stringify() the result of toObject(), defaults to false
> - `useProjection` set to `true` to omit fields that are excluded in this document's projection. Unless you specified a projection, this
>   will omit any field that has `select: false` in the schema.

Comment: Works like a charm. I've searched a lot for an example like your.
https://prnt.sc/uufqfa

Answer (score 0):

Then try like this

```
let res = await Model.save();
return res._doc;
```